# web2py cron error message

Tags: python, windows, web2py, background-process

When running web2py (1.99.4) on windows, I see the following message on the console

```
WARNING:web2py.cron:WEB2PY CRON: Disabled because no file locking
```

I don't see this when I'm running on linux.

- Why am I getting this message?
- Does this mean it is not possible to use the web2py cron on windows?
- How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: CRON settings are in web2py.py file

Answer (score 1):

You need [pywin32](http://starship.python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/Downloads.html).

[Source](https://groups.google.com/group/web2py/browse_thread/thread/7d577b75534fe8b8?pli=1)